# OS X 10.9 Mavericks - Localhost Setup with VHosts

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, osx-mavericks, vhosts

I have just been trying to setup a local apache server on osx. Everything was going well until I enabled vhosts.

When I navigate to a site setup in vhosts (local.dev) all I get is a 403 forbidden error saying you do not have permission to access / on this server.

The route of the site in question is '/www/local/public/'. The folder path exists and running `apachectl -S` and the syntax of the vhosts file was correct.

I have looked at the permissions of the folder and have even tried setting everyone to read and write, but no luck. I have set my permissions on the folder to read/write as well as permissions for the _www group.

If you have any ideas on where I am going wrong that would be much appreciated!

I have looked for a few answers on here but not been able to find anything that has worked for me.

Looking at the default document root for apache, the only permission I have missing on the /www/ folder is for an account called 'system'. I am unable to add this system account to the permissions of the folder as it does not appear in the get info option on the folder.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all of my questions it seems, I have found an answer!

I managed to get everything working smoothly by adding the following to my `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file inside of the `<VirtualHost *:80>` that was setup for local.dev

```
<Directory "/www/local/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

So the overall vhosts config for `local.dev` would look like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/local/public"
    ServerName local.dev
    <Directory "/www/local/public">
        ... Above code here ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I added this, then restarted apache, and everything worked smoothly.